# DropdownButtonFormField in flutter isn't centered when using icon, and when using suffixIcon in its InputDecoration, it won't be pressable

Tags: flutter, dropdown

DropdownButtonFormField in flutter isn't centered when using icon, and when using suffixIcon in its InputDecoration, it won't be pressable. here's my code:

```
 Container(
      height: 56,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.val == null ? AppColors.INPUT_COLOR : null,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        iconSize: 24,
        items: widget.items,
        icon: Container(),
        value: widget.val,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
            ),
            // focusColor: Colors.transparent,
            focusedBorder: AppBorders.focusedBorder,
            enabledBorder: widget.val == null
                ? AppBorders.noBorder
                : AppBorders.defaultBorder,
            disabledBorder: AppBorders.defaultBorder,
            border: widget.val == null
                ? AppBorders.noBorder
                : AppBorders.defaultBorder,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 16),
            labelText: widget.label,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.MAIN_TEXT.withOpacity(0.5),
            )),
      ),
    );
```

When i use suffixIcon in input decoration, the dropdown won't open when i press on the icon.
Furthermore, if I use icon of dropdownButtonFormField like this:

```
Container(
      height: 56,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.val == null ? AppColors.INPUT_COLOR : null,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        iconSize: 24,
        items: widget.items,
        value: widget.val,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            // focusColor: Colors.transparent,
            focusedBorder: AppBorders.focusedBorder,
            enabledBorder: widget.val == null
                ? AppBorders.noBorder
                : AppBorders.defaultBorder,
            disabledBorder: AppBorders.defaultBorder,
            border: widget.val == null
                ? AppBorders.noBorder
                : AppBorders.defaultBorder,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 16),
            labelText: widget.label,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.MAIN_TEXT.withOpacity(0.5),
            )),
      ),
    );
```

the icon will not be centered. To be more specific, this is how i need it to look like:
[image]

but instead, it looks like this: [image]

As you can see, when there is no item selected for the dropdown, the icon is not aligned with the text

Comment: would be helpful if you could share the screen shot of what you got here

Comment: @TryHarder, thank you for your comment. I added the images.

Comment: I'm noy quite sure why but it was because of the background color. In the new app design they removed the background color and it got fixed... weird...